# How is the tree constructed for Kraft equality check + instant decoding?

Tags: coding-theory

I have 3 elements code with words of length {2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4}

The Kraft inequality for first one is:

$$
\frac{1}{3 ^ 2}
+
\frac{1}{3 ^ 3}
+
\frac{1}{3 ^ 3}
+
\frac{1}{3 ^ 3}
+
\frac{1}{3 ^ 3}
+
\frac{1}{3 ^ 3}
+
\frac{1}{3 ^ 4}
+
\frac{1}{3 ^ 4}
$$

which is less than 1, fine.

but I don't understand how to construct tree as next step for validation

For example:

do I have to put the shortest words first e.g on the left and avoid having more than one on "straight" edge?

[image]

So the code would be

Shortest: 00

Second Shortest: 01

Third Shortest: 10

Longest: 11

do I get this right?

Answer (score 3):

Kraft inequality in the form you gave
$$\sum_{c_i\in C} q^{-\ell_i}\leq 1,$$ with $q=3$ implies you have a ternary tree. This means 3 branches instead of 2, and you can label them ${0,1,2}$ starting from the left.